# Swift framework not generating objective c header code in -swift file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-frameworks

I've created a framework in swift and it generates the -Swift file. The issue I'm seeing though is the objective c header stub methods in the file aren't being generated.

The code for the example class I'm trying to get a method for is:

```
public class BeaconService {
    public func getAllBeacons() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

And the file shows:

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 2.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.6 clang-   700.1.76)
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
# include <uchar.h>
#elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
#endif

typedef struct _NSZone NSZone;

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(swift_name)
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X) __attribute__((swift_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) &&         __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted) 
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME)     SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
#endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

- I'm on Xcode 7.1 and the deployment target is 9.1.
- I've tried dropping the target to 8 with no luck.
- The file's target is the framework.

This has been driving me up a wall for the last few hours so any suggestions would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify @objc before class declaration in order to expose your class to Objective-C:

```
@objc public class BeaconService: NSObject {
    public func getAllBeacons() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Also make sure to subclass from NSObject.

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help for me (

Comment: I hit this exact issue although I already had @objc and the code was working fine with macOS.  When I went to build for iOS I had to add `public` to all classes and methods I wanted exposed to Objective-C !  Didn't need this for macOS :/